# How can I load and execute a lua file from within another lua file

Tags: lua

I have a lua script which is run using the command line interpreter, the script needs to load a table from a file.
The table is stored like this:

```
create_object_action = {
    reflexive = true,
    which_base_type = 29,
    how_many_min = 1,
    how_many_range = 0,
    velocity_relative = false,
    direction_relative = true,
    random_distance = 0
}
```

How can I load the data in the table into the global namespace?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
dofile "mytables.lua"
```